The relation between intensity and electric field
For a plane wave of the form $E=E_0 \cos(\omega t- k z)$, the intensity is $I=\frac{1}{2}c\epsilon_0E_0^2$. This can be derived by noting that $I=\langle S\rangle$, where $\langle 
\,\rangle$ denotes time average over one cycle, and $\mathbf{S}=\frac{1}{\mu_0}\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}$ is the Poynting vector.
I have seen that some authors use the similar relation $I=\frac{1}{2}c\epsilon_0 |\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r},t)|^2$ for other cases such as short laser pulses. So the question arises that when this relation for intensity can be used. And is it accurate or an approximation when we have not a monochromatic plane wave?

Related, but I'm not sure if it is a duplicate of (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/744083/electromagnetic-field-intensity-square-law-power-poynting-vector?rq=1)

@Ruffolo, That post concerns the connection between the relations for intensity in scalar wave theory of light and vector wave theory of light. My post is about the different forms resulting from the relation $I=\langle S\rangle$ in the vector wave theory (i.e. electromagnetism).
